# Changing mouse cursor in kivy

Tags: python, cursor, pygame, mouse, kivy

I searched how to change the cursor icon in kivy, but the only way I found is to change it directly in pygame. Pygame doesn't support colored or animated gifs as its cursor, so I made an Image widget with Screen as parent and set it to follow the mouse position in the window.

```
    ScreenManager:
        Screen:
            MyMouse:
                Image:
```

The problem is... my image doesn't stays always at the top. Popup and Spinner widgets are drawn over it.

I'm probably doing it the wrong way...

Is there a simple way to do what I want?

Comment: You could add your mouse cursor widget to the Window (kivy.core.window.Window.add_widget) rather than putting it in the normal widget tree. There are still some cases (like popups) that it wouldn't work for though.

Comment: I tried this, but I need the mouse to be over popups too!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Scatter instead of Image like this:

```
class MyMouse(Scatter):
    self.add_widget('yourimage.jpg')
    self.auto_bring_to_front = True
```

Comment: Popups and spinners are still displayed over the image.  =(

Comment: Kivy gives us a control over order of widgets only while adding them, so the order of add_widget() method is very important here. If you generate your widgets dynamically and they are showing of top, there is no way to bring ones behind them to the front. You can only delete old image and create a new one.